# How do I change the display attributes of the YouTube subscribe widget?

Tags: html, youtube, widget

The YT subscribe widget via iframe has too much info for me, is too big.

Is there a way to add some parameters to make the iframe smaller or with less info so all fits in a smaller area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manipulate the size of the YouTube subscribe widget via the *height* and *width* parameters of the iFrame.

In most cases the widget will adjust itself to a way that will fit best. The results may not always have the correct alignment or fit all of the information in, so some playing around is required.

I created [a jsFiddle with an example](http://jsfiddle.net/DGtzL/).

Sidenote: You can not alter what information appears in the widget without somehow chopping it off via the height and width parameters, which I **do not** suggest you do.

Comment: I was really interested, if there are more parameters that can be useed. For now I fall back to a simple button.

Comment: @PeterMmm: What was the code that you used for the "simple button"

Comment: A button with image from http://www.youtube.com/t/creators_downloads that links directly to my channel http://www.youtube.com/user/<user-name>/ .